# Unexpected Result with GCD Priorities

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I've been experimenting with GCD priorities recently. Here's the snippet of code that I've been working with.

```
for _ in 1...1000 {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        for _ in 1...10000000 {
            let _ = sin(0.64739812)
        }
        print("Finished a default")
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0))     {
            for _ in 1...10000 {
                let _ = sin(0.64739812)
            }
            print("Finished a high")
        }
    }
}
```

I expected it to print

```
Finished a default
Finished a high
// Repeat default and high alternating back and forth 1000 times (because there are 1000 loops)
```

But what actually happened was the logs printed

```
Finished a default
Finished a high
Finished a default x 21
Finished a high
Finished a default
Finished a high x 20
Finished a default x 977
Finished a high x 978
```

It makes sense in the beginning, alternating a little bit. Even 21 defaults in a row makes some sense. But then it does 977 default blocks without processing a single high block. I assume this is happening because the dispatcher is very busy dealing with everything else going on. But still, it's a high priority queue vs a default priority queue.

Does anybody have any insights as to what's going on?

#### Edit 1

```
for _ in 1...1000 {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        print("Starting a default")
        for i in 1...10000000 {
            let _ = sin(Double(i))
        }
        print("Finished a default")
    }
}
for _ in 1...1000 {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
        print("Starting a high")
        for i in 1...10000000 {
            let _ = sin(Double(i))
        }
        print("Finished a high")
    }
}

print("Done Dispatching Everything")
```

Here I would expect a couple `default`s and a couple `high`s to execute before printing `Done Dispatching Everything`, and then to execute all the `high`s then all the `default`s.

However, here are the results:

```
Starting a default x6
Done Dispatching Everything // at this point, all the high and default blocks have been successfully submitted for execution.
Starting a high
Finished a default
Starting a default
Finished a default
Starting a default
Finished a default
Starting a default
Finished a default
Starting a default
Finished a default
Starting a default
Finished a default
Starting a default
Finished a default
Starting a default
Finished a high
Starting a high
Finished a default
Starting a default
Finished a default
Finished a default
Starting a default
Starting a default
Finished a default
Starting a default
Finished a default
Starting a default
Finished a default
Starting a default
Finished a high
Starting a high
Finished a default
Starting a default
Finished a default
Starting a default
// A sequence that looks like the above for around 1500 lines.
Started+Finished a high x ~500
```

So what's happening is that even after everything is scheduled, `default` is happening significantly more than `high`. And then after all the `default`s have finished, the `high`s finally start to execute and finish in bulk.

#### Edit 2

Another block

```
for _ in 1...1000 {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
        print("Starting a high")
        for i in 1...10000000 {
            let _ = sin(Double(i))
        }
        print("Finished a high")
    }
}
for _ in 1...1000 {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        print("Starting a default")
        for i in 1...10000000 {
            let _ = sin(Double(i))
        }
        print("Finished a default")
    }
}

print("Done Dispatching Everything")
```

And the results blow my mind. It does the exact same thing as my second example, (Edit 1). Even though the `high`s all get scheduled before the `default`s, it still executes the `default` blocks first!

#### Edit 3

Last example, I promise

```
for _ in 1...1000 {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
        print("Starting a high")
        for i in 1...10000000 {
            let _ = sin(Double(i))
        }
        print("Finished a high")
    }
}
for _ in 1...1000 {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
        print("Starting a background")
        for i in 1...10000000 {
            let _ = sin(Double(i))
        }
        print("Finished a background")
    }
}

print("Done Dispatching Everything")
```

This executes exactly as expected. All the `high`s run, then all the `background`s run, with no exceptions at all. However this is significantly different in execution than edit 2, however in theory should be the exact same.

Comment: The loop enqueues 1000 *async* A's to a conc-Q. If *any* of them completes, it'll kick off a B request. Simplified: Lets assume the `DEFAULT` can do 4 at once (4 threads, 1000-in). So it picks up 4, runs them. This will spawn 4 reqs to `HIGH`. Then it grabs the next 4 A while 4 B are running. And so on. They interleave. The original assumption is (simplified) that the 4 high-B tasks run before the next 4 A tasks are picked up from the def-Q. And hence you'll get a somewhat even distribution between A's and B's completing, because A's take much longer to execute (10000000 vs 10000 iterations).

Comment: @hnh yes, that's what I was expecting. I am enqueueing task B (high priority) after the work in task A, but because the default queue can only process so many at a time, there should be interwoven task Bs throughout the task A executions. But it ends up just running A over and over, even though B (with a higher priority) has been successfully dispatched. So despite it's priority, it's behind in the queue.

Comment: @bclymer I don't know how long `for _ in 1...10000 { sin }` (or even 10000000) takes to execute on your machine, but all those `print`s are quite likely much slower. Your test may be flawed. Try again and capture the events in a preallocated structure (just a threadsafe array with a cursor).

Comment: Also make sure that the compiler doesn't compile either `for _ in 1...10000000 { let _ = sin(0.64739812) }` into a nothing (or unwraps either into a single sin(0.64) call ...

Comment: @hnh I've added another example which more clearly shows the problem.

Comment: I tried your edit 2 on MacOS 10.12b with Swift 2.3 (just 100 iterations) on a MacBook and it runs most high first, has a small window where it interleaves (~20 reqs), and then finishes the defaults. Seems to work for me. What platform do you test on? I don't think it is out of question that HIGH=DEFAULT on some, as your 3rd sample suggests.

Comment: What about edit 2? Where you enqueue all the `high`s first, and then all the `default`s. In that instance, you would think there is no way a `default` could execute before a `high`, right? On 9.3.5, it definitely does. I'll grab a 10b device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122239/discussion-between-bclymer-and-hnh).

Answer (score 0):

check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion

don't print to standard output {dispatch all printing to some low priority serial queue) and check all the results again.

try this in your Playground

```
import Dispatch

let pq = DispatchQueue(label: "print", qos: .background)
let g = DispatchGroup()
func dprint(_ items: Any...) {
    pq.async(group: g) {
        var r = items.map{ String(describing: $0) }.joined(separator: " ")
        print(r)
    }
}

let q1 = DispatchQueue(label: "q1", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent)
let q2 = DispatchQueue(label: "q2", qos: .userInteractive, attributes: .concurrent)

for i in 0..<10 {
    q1.async(group: g) {
        dprint("q1", i, "started")
        for i in 0..<100 {
            _ = sin(Double(i))
        }
        dprint("q1", i, "finished")
    }
}
for i in 0..<10 {
    q2.async(group: g) {
        dprint("\tq2", i, "started")
        for i in 0..<100 {
            _ = sin(Double(i))
        }
        dprint("\tq2", i, "finished")
    }
}
g.wait()
print("end of test")
```

it should print (don't expect the same!!) something more realistic

```
q1 0 started
q1 1 started
q1 2 started
    q2 0 started
    q2 1 started
    q2 2 started
    q2 3 started
    q2 0 finished
    q2 4 started
    q2 1 finished
    q2 2 finished
    q2 5 started
    q2 6 started
    q2 3 finished
    q2 7 started
    q2 6 finished
    q2 8 started
    q2 5 finished
    q2 7 finished
    q2 4 finished
    q2 9 started
    q2 8 finished
    q2 9 finished
q1 2 finished
q1 3 started
q1 0 finished
q1 4 started
q1 1 finished
q1 6 started
q1 5 started
q1 4 finished
q1 6 finished
q1 7 started
q1 8 started
q1 5 finished
q1 3 finished
q1 9 started
q1 7 finished
q1 8 finished
q1 9 finished
end of test
```